# Error when previewing an answer when user is not associated yet on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, android-app, markdown-preview

To reproduce:

1. Go to a Stack Exchange site you are *not associated* with
2. Open any question, tap *Add an answer*, then compose an answer
3. Click *Preview*
4. Get an error message

   > The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site

Preview seems to work once you are associated to the site.

Comment: Repro'd on v1.0.83.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Generally when you preview an answer, the preview is generated by `/questions/{id}/answers/add?preview=true` which does validation and depends on the user existing.  When a user doesn't exist on a site, we'll use `/questions/{id}/answers/render` instead.